# Show for an irreducible polynomial $f(x) \in F[x]$ of degree $n$, $n$ divides $[E:F]$ where $E/F$ is the splitting field of $f(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field

Let $F$ be a field. I want to show that for an irreducible polynomial $f(x)$ in $F[x]$ of degree $n$, and for a splitting field $E/F$ of $f(x)$, we have $n \mid [E:F]$.

Can anyone provide any hints for me to think about this?

Thank you.

Comment: Let $\alpha \in E$ be a root of $f$ and consider the field $F(\alpha)$. Then you have $F \subseteq F(\alpha) \subseteq E$. Try to work with that.

Comment: If you know that a splitting field is the field which contains all roots of $f(X)$ and that you can construct a finite extension of $F$ containing a root of $f$ by constructing the quotient $L=F[X]/(f)$, then $[E:L][L:F]$ and $[L:F]=\deg(f)$ which you can exhibit a basis of using the root.

This can also be found in *Galois Theory* by Escofier on page 60.

Comment: @Eoin so basically L is a finite extension of F constructed by taking the quotient ring of F[x]/(f(x)). F is in L, L is in E since E is a splitting field of F and L is a field extension of F. Hence, [E:L][L:F]=[E:F]. But why is [L:F] = deg(f)?

Comment: @jstnchng Yes that's the idea. You can show that if $\pi$ is the mapping taking $F[X]$ to the quotient that $\pi(X)$ is a root to the polynomial $f(X)$. Then using the euclidean algorithm you can deduce that the quotient is the set of all polynomials of degree strictly less than $\deg (f)$. This has basis $\{1,\pi(X)=x, ... , x^{\deg(f)-1}\}$ so the $[L:F]=\deg(f)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume familiarity with the result if $F$ is a field, $L$ a finite extension of $F$ containing subfield $K$ such that $F \subseteq K$, then $$[L:F]=[L:K][K:F]$$
If this is not familiar, it is not to difficult to show using the concept of finding a basis for $L$ over $F$.

Now consider the irreducible polynomial $f\in F[X]$, with $\deg(f)=n$ and $E$ the splitting field of $f$ over $F$. By definition, $E$ is the field containing all roots of the polynomial $f$. We wish to construct a field $F(x)$, with $x$ a root of $f$, such that $F\subseteq F(x) \subseteq E$ and $[F(x):F]=\deg(f)$.

Let $\pi:F[X]\rightarrow F[X]/(f)$ be the canonical projection of the coordinate ring onto the quotient ring (i.e. $\forall g\in F[X], g\mapsto g+(f)$). We consider the the following: $L$ contains a root of $f$ and all elements of $F$, $L=F[X]/(f)$ is a field, $[L:F]=\deg(f)$.

Clearly the quotient ring is indeed a ring. We make the distinction now that $\pi(X)=X+(f)=x$ so that for $g = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k X^k \in F[X]$ we have $\pi(g)=\pi(\sum_{k=0}^n a_kX^k)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k$ where we have now dropped the notation $(f)$ for convenience. Since $\pi(f)=f(\pi(X))=f(x)=0$, we have $x\in L$ is a root of $f$.

Also, for every $g\in F[X]$ we have $f\mid g$ or $(f,g)=1$ since $f$ is an irreducible polynomial. In the former case, $g\mapsto 0$. Thus, every nonzero element $g$ of $L$ is realizable as the image of a relatively prime polynomial to $f$. By Bézout's identity there are polynomials $s,t\in F[X]$ such that $1=fs+gt$. Since $x$ is a root of $f$, evaluating the polynomials in this expression at $x$ yields $1=g(x)t(x)$. Thus every nonzero element $g(\pi(X))=g(x)\in L$ has an inverse, showing $L$ is a field.

Finally, we show $[L:F]=\deg(f)$. To do this we show explicitly $\{1,x,x^2,...,x^{\deg(f)-1}\}$ is a basis for $L$. Linear independence is clear since if there existed scalars $a_0,...,a_{\deg(f)-1}$ such that $\sum_{k=0}^{\deg(f)-1} a_kx^k=0$, then $p(X)=\sum_{k=0}^{\deg(f)-1} a_kX^k$ has lesser degree than $f$ and vanishes at $x$. Since $f$ is an irreducible polynomial $f\mid p$ which forces $p(X)=0$ and all the scalars are $0$.

Consider $g\in F[X]$. By Euclidean division we can find $q,r\in F[X]$ such that $g=fq+r$ with $0\leq\deg(r)<\deg(f)$. Then $g(x)=r(x)$ which can be realized via the basis suggested showing that we were not wrong to claim $\{1,x,...,x^{\deg(f)-1}\}$ is a basis for $L$.

Our assertion is then made using the result we assumed familiarity with since, for $E$ a splitting field of $f$, a polynomial of degree $n$, we have $$[E:F]=[E:L][L:F]=[E:L]n$$
in other words $n|[E:F]$.